# Download successful but only part of the file is downloaded

Tags: php, download, file-get-contents, readfile

I want my users to be able to download a video once they click on the download button. When they click to download it downloads fine but it only downloads about 200 bytes of the total 40mb. What is going on?

Here is a sample of the code I'm using

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.mp4");
header('Pragma: no-cache');
$download = "$url/$filename.mp4";
readfile($download);
```

Comment: May be there is an error in that 200 bytes? Try to view it like text. And explore your error.log.

Answer (score -1):

Everything is ok here. but maybe the path is not correct. Try the code below. you will get what's wrong:

```
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.mp4");
//header('Pragma: no-cache');
$download = "$url/$filename.mp4";
readfile($download);
```

Always check if `file_exists` before allowing your download script to execute.